# Image link to page

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a logo in the header of my website and I want the logo to direct you to the home page when it is clicked.  In the code, the anchor is just surrounding the `<img>` tag, but on the website the entire div is clickable.  How can I make it so that just when I hover on the image it is clickable, not the entire `div`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <a href="@Url.Action("index", "home")">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Content/img/stars.jpg" alt="Stars" />
        </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer.  I needed to add the style `display: inline-block` to the `<img>` tag.